# Asset property of AVAssetTrack is nil sometimes

Tags: ios, asynchronous, avfoundation, avasset

I'm trying to get the `asset` property from an `AVAssetTrack` object, but it's `nil` sometimes. It seems like the problem occurs only after I use `Dispatch.main.async`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading), it's necessary to use `loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:, completion:)` to avoid blocking the main thread, and return to the main thread after loading is done.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoInAppBundleURL)
let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
assert(track.asset != nil) // passes
track.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [#keyPath(AVAssetTrack.asset)]) {
    assert(track.asset != nil) // passes
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        assert(track.asset != nil) // FAILS
        // [...]
    }
}
```

What I found out is:

- It makes no difference whether I'm running on a device or the
  simulator.
- It seems not to be a problem with the video / videoURL.
  The video is part of the main bundle, I tried both .mp4 and .mov
  files and I made sure the video works by displaying it via an
  AVPlayerViewController.

Here is a working [demo project](https://github.com/storylife/VideoExportDemo).

I'm also wondering: why is `AVAssetTrack`'s `asset` property optional? (all!! the other properties are non optional)

*Note: this question has been edited after reading Matt's helpful comments and further investigation.*

Comment: You are forming your keys incorrectly. Use key paths, eg `#keyPath(AVURLAsset.tracks)`.

Comment: Also please note that you do not need to use asynchronous loading just to ask for `assetTrack.asset`.

Comment: Also where is this video coming from? Is it in your bundle? Or did you just download it? If the latter, maybe that’s the problem: the downloaded file is being removed from temporary storage before you have a chance to use it.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your helpful comments, I edited the question and narrowed down the problem. The video is in my bundle and works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reproduced the issue, with some tweaking of your github example, like this:

```
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoInAppBundleURL)
    let tracksKey = #keyPath(AVAsset.tracks)
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [tracksKey]) {
        let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            assert(track.asset != nil) // fails
        }
    }
```

Okay, but now watch closely as I perform an amazing trick:

```
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoInAppBundleURL)
    let tracksKey = #keyPath(AVAsset.tracks)
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [tracksKey]) {
        let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(asset) // <-- amazing trick
            assert(track.asset != nil) // passes!
        }
    }
```

Whoa! All I did was add a `print` statement — and now suddenly the very same assertion passes. This in fact is parallel to your original statement (which you later edited out) that "Sometimes the problems are gone, when stepping through the code with the debugger.”

So, now, my suspicions being thoroughly aroused, I did something unbelievably clever (even if I do say so myself). I removed the `print(asset)`, but I switched the scheme’s configuration from Debug to Release. Presto, the assertion still passes.

So what you’ve found is a quirk of the compiler — dare I call it a bug?

But wait, there’s more. You asked, quite reasonably, why `asset` is Optional. It’s because it’s `weak`:

```
weak open var asset: AVAsset? { get }
```

So there’s your answer. The track has only a weak reference to its asset. If we pass the track down into an asynchronous queue, and we do *not* bring the asset itself along with us, then the weak reference lets go and the asset is lost — in a Debug build.

Hope this helps. You are probably waiting for me to make some grand conclusory statement about whether this constitutes a bug, but I’m not going to, sorry. I’ve provided two workarounds (use a Release build, or deliberately carry the asset reference down into the async queue) and that’s as far as I can go.

Comment: Great! Thank you! – I bought a hardcopy of your iOS 12 book today :)

Comment: If you can lift it you’re doing better than I can! :)

Comment: Btw I did submit this as a bug [report](https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-10501) but I fully expect them to reply it’s not a bug.

Comment: you deserve a trophy for this answer.  Going to add some extra info here.  Not only do you get a nil AVAsset but unless you pass along the AVAsset it appears the preferredTransform is incorrect.Meaning from what I am experiencing if the AVAsset is released due to it's weak nature then the preferredTransform of the track is incorrect.  Your answer helped me.  Passing the asset along with the track helped me fix this.